# The meaning of “sure could have done"?

Tags: word-usage

I read this sentence:

> I **sure could have used** this when I was in school!

I am confusing about **sure could have used**. How to understand it?

The background is:

> One of the most valuable features in Word 2016, at least from the perspective of students and researchers, is its ability to automatically generate bibliographies or lists of works cited in any of a variety of well-known formats, including MLA and APA (the big two for academia). **I sure could have used this when I was in school!**

Answer (score 1):

> **[sure](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sure#:%7E:text=English%20Language%20Learners%20Definition%20of,sure)** <sub>adjective</sub>
>
> 1a: marked by or given to feelings of confident certainty
> "I'm sure I'm right"
>
> **sure** <sub>adverb</sub>
> see also: **surely**
>
> 1: in a sure manner

We can thus rewrite your sentence to say:

> I **certainly** could have used this when I was in school!
> I **am confident that I** could have used this when I was in school!

"sure" here is used as an adverb, modifying the modal verb "could".  In what way could I have used it?  In a sure or certain way.